# Cannot clear output text: tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox

When the following code is ran and the tkinter button is clicked; it produces the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scypy\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\modpu\Documents\Python\DelMe.py", line 5, in click
    OutputBox.delete(0, END)
  File "D:\Scypy\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3133, in delete
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', index1, index2)
_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"
```

For some reason the code successfully clears the text in the input box but fails to clear the text in the output box (it crashes instead).

Any help for this would be appreciated, thank you.

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    MainTextBox.delete(0, END)  #This works
    OutputBox.delete(0, END) #This doesn't work

GUI = Tk()
MainTextBox = Entry(GUI, width = 20, bg = "white")
MainTextBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
Button(GUI, text = "SUBMIT", width = 6, command = click).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
OutputBox = Text(GUI, width = 100, height = 10, wrap = WORD, background = "orange")
OutputBox.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
OutputBox.insert(END, "Example text")

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: text and entry widgets are different. At the error says, `0` is an invalid index for a text widget.

Comment: This tripped me up as well. As Bryan (and the error) says, 0 is an invalid index for a text widget. In a text widget, you need to use '1.0' instead of '0'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, this is the solution:

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    MainTextBox.delete(0, END)  
    OutputBox.delete('1.0', END) 

GUI = Tk()
MainTextBox = Entry(GUI, width = 20, bg = "white")
MainTextBox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
Button(GUI, text = "SUBMIT", width = 6, command = click).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
OutputBox = Text(GUI, width = 100, height = 10, wrap = WORD, background = "orange")
OutputBox.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
OutputBox.insert(END, "Example text")

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what the difference was. Otherwise the reader has to compare your code to the original line by line and character by character.

Comment: You solved my problem, but it is so weird! Why would index be a string with float number inside?

Comment: The only **difference** in the code is in the **last line of click() function**. The **argument** in `OutputBox.delete(0, END)` is changed to => `('1.0', END)` because text widgets must have index **1.0** and not 0.

Comment: @DC007744 Thx! I couldn't get anything else to work expect using a string with '1.0'. Why is this not documented? Absurd since the others just take a `0`

Answer (score 2):

```
def click(): 
    OutputBox.delete('1.0', END)
```

Sometimes system doesn't support integer when you try it to run in IDLE, I know its frustrating but yeah this sure works.

Comment: Please format your answer with sections that are code and the ones that are explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
def click(): 
    OutputBox.delete('0', END)
```

Worked for me in Python 3.8.1 as '1.0' was throwing errors.